# GWT : image not appearing when run on server

Tags: gwt

i have an application in GWT , where i am using some images.. 
the image appear fine when i run on development mode in eclipse .
but when i run my application on tomcat/local server (after compilation)
everything works fine but.. image just disappear ..

the image is in war folder .

any idea what could be the reason

Comment: wrong path? if packaged as a war-file,by default the name of the war is appended at the beginning of the path.

Comment: Please show the code where you create your image.

Comment: It's probably a wrong path, especially if your image was located in your module's `src/public_html`. A quick way to find out is inspect the image on your browser, copy the URL, then paste it into a new tab and see if that loads.

Comment: I'd bet on a wrong path too; most likely due to the _servlet context path_ (link uses a domain-relative path such as `/foo` rather than being relative to `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()`; works in DevMode as the app is deployed to `/`, not in servlet container where it's deployed at `/myapp`)

Comment: I have had the same problem and searched for hours, finally i removed the "/" at the beginning of the path and the image appeared.

Comment: here is the code ::  <div style="padding-left:800px">
 <g:Image url="../close.jpg" ui:field="closeImage"></g:Image>
 </div>

Comment: removing "/"  worked , thanks